# When is a linear operator on $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$ a multiplication?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

The title says it all, really. Suppose that I have a linear operator $T$ from $C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ into itself, where $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (e.g. the unit ball if it helps). I know it is continuous and therefore bounded.

My question is : Is there a criterion to establish that $(Tf)(x)=G(x)f(x)$, where $G(x)=(T1)(x)$?

It could be only Stack-Exchange worthy, I don't know: happy to be demoted in that case.

For context : the $T$ I have in mind is the first order (in some asymptotic sense) of a solution operator associated to an elliptic PDE. Under some regularity hypothesis, I can show that indeed $T= G\cdot$, but I suspect this is true without these extra assumptions.